# Generate Random Variable with Certain Cumulative Distribution in R

Tags: r, simulation, cdf

Does anyone know the algorithm to generate random variable from $F(x) = \Pi_{i=1}^n F_i(x)$ distribution where $i=1,2,..,n$ in R?

Answer (score 1):

That's equivalent to saying Pr{X<sub>1</sub> <= x & X<sub>2</sub> <= x & ... & X<sub>n</sub> <= x} for independent X's. Generate from each of the F<sub>i</sub>'s independently, and take the max.  Independent generation gives you an ensemble meeting the individual distribution requirements, and taking the max meets the requirement of the joint probability statement.

In the special case where the F<sub>i</sub>'s are invertible and are the same for all i, this can be done with a single inverse transformation. Let's call F<sub>i</sub>(x) === G(x) to avoid tripping over notation.  Then F(x) = G<sup>n</sup>(x), and by the [inverse transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling) theorem G<sup>n</sup>(X) is distributed uniformly between 0 and 1 for random variable X.  Therefore, for U ~ uniform(0,1) and starting with your statement about F(x):

- F(X) = G<sup>n</sup>(X) = U
- G(X) = U<sup>1/n</sup>
- X = G<sup>-1</sup>(U<sup>1/n</sup>)

This gives a one-step method for generating the max of n independent and identically distributed random variates X, as opposed to having to generate n of them and take the max.

Comment: Oh, okay, I'll try that. Thank you so much for the explanation @pjs